# Как вывести несколько инфоблоков внутри inclue bitrix?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

У меня есть вкладка "Услуги", при этом внутри лежит 3 инфоблока "Категории", мне нужно вывести их названия с картинкой.
Использую news.list со своим шаблоном, но как передать в include несколько инфоблоков не понимаю.
Что посоветуете? Нужно будет пилить свой компонент или обойтись как-то? Да чтобы и всё оптимально было.

Comment: А нельзя просто 3 раза вызвать компонент, указывая разные инфоблоки? Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @rusgeli , я думал есть более оптимальный вариант

Comment: Не, бесспорно вы можете не используя компоненты вручную через `GetList` получить исключительно необходимые вам элементы/разделы ИБ и выводить их вместе, но, мне кажется, это не тот случай, который требует таких заморочек